# How to perform this mobility calculation?

Tags: excel, vba, stata

I have the data on the mobility of inventors between firms. For each inventor, there are multiple rows in the old firm and the new firm, with each row presenting the patent she/he produced in a given year in the respective firm (please see the screenshot). I am only interested in two rows in this dataset - the row containing the last patent the inventor produced in the old firm and the row containing the first patent in the new firm. How do I keep only these two rows for each inventor and delete the rest? The inventor in the example is 38592732 who moved from Science Union to Adir. I only want to keep rows 62 and 63 and delete the rest. –
Any help in Stata or Excel will be helpful. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?  This is not a code-for-you service, so helping with specific issues would require the specific issue you are having with appropriate background information (including your code).

Comment: This question does not have anything to do with Excel or VBA

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible data set (using for example `dataex`) would have given you a solution that would have required less adaptation, but the example below should show you how it can be done.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte inventorID str1 patentID str9 firm int year
1 "A" "old_firm"  2000
1 "B" "old_firm"  2001
1 "C" "new_firm"  2002
1 "D" "new_firm"  2003
1 "E" "new_firm"  2004
1 "F" "new_firm"  2005
2 "G" "old_firm2" 2000
2 "H" "old_firm2" 2001
2 "I" "new_firm2" 2004
2 "J" "new_firm2" 2005
end

* Sort data on inventor and year
sort inventorID year

* Identify last patent as row where inventor is the same on the next row but firm is not
gen lastPatent  = (inventorID == inventorID[_n+1] & firm != firm[_n+1])
* Identify last patent as row where inventor is the same on the previous row but firm is not
gen firstPatent = (inventorID == inventorID[_n-1] & firm != firm[_n-1])

* Keep only rows categorized as first or last patent
keep if lastPatent == 1 | firstPatent == 1
```